# Next 13.4 issue with providers and root layout

Tags: typescript, layout, metadata, next.js13, themeprovider

I'm getting ReactServerComponentsError when I wrap my providers around children in RootLayout.

Below is my root layout:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import { Space_Mono, Work_Sans } from "next/font/google";
import { Providers } from "./providers";
import { Metadata } from "next";

export const space = Space_Mono({
    weight: ["400", "700"],
    subsets: ["latin"],
});

export const work = Work_Sans({
    weight: ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"],
    display: "fallback", //ensure font won't flash to default on reload
    subsets: ["latin"],
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: "Game-Scope",
    description: "Your one-stop destination for all things gaming.",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={work.className}>
                <Providers>{children}</Providers>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

And this is my providers file:

```
"use client";

import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { SkeletonTheme } from "react-loading-skeleton";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";
import StyledComponentsRegistry from "@/lib/registry";
import theme from "@/theme";

export function Providers({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient();

    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <StyledComponentsRegistry>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <SkeletonTheme
                        baseColor="#313131"
                        highlightColor="#525252"
                    >
                        {children}
                    </SkeletonTheme>
                </ThemeProvider>
            </StyledComponentsRegistry>
            <ReactQueryDevtools />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
}
```

I'm getting this error [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBIwp.png) even thought my RootLayout is not marked with "use client", am I missing something here? and if so what is the right way to wrap my providers around the layout and how do I use metadata in this case.

I tried wrapping the providers directly in my RootLayout but this means I won't be able to use metadata as well because I'll need to mark my root layout with "use client" and it cannot be used in client component.

Comment: What is your Next.js version?

Comment: 13.4.19 to be specific.